# How to remove \n from string in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my string and I want to remove some characters from string. My code is below

```
"{  \"userpass\" : \"\",  \"apikey\" : \"=\",  \"deviceid\" : \"\",  \"username\" : \"\"}"
```

and I want to convert into this format.

```
{ 
    "userpass" : "",
    "username" : "",
    "deviceid" : "",
    "apikey" : "="
}
```

How to remove `\` from string to make JSON string proper?

Comment: you want remove `\n` or `\\`

Comment: Please Check my updated question

Comment: This string is pretty-printed JSON. You should **not** try to decode it by doing character replacement/parsing but by using proper JSON methods.

Comment: my actual requirement is to pass json dictionary to server.

Comment: ok.than how to should i post this json to server using alamofire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `json` in String response if you want to get dictionary from that try this, Here `str` is your string

```
let str = "{  \"userpass\" : \"\",  \"apikey\" : \"=\",  \"deviceid\" : \"\",  \"username\" : \"\"}"
let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
do {
    let dic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
    print(dic)
}
catch let e as NSError {
    print(e.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Hi Nirav.
Requirement is i have to pass dictionary instead of array as parameter to server.
how to do that.can you please explain?

Comment: Check my edited answer. You will get dictionary.

Comment: Yes.i am getting dictionary.now question is how to pass it to server using alamofire?

Comment: You can find that on `alamofire` document

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/121540/alamofire-tutorial-getting-started) or this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/alamofire-beginner-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

If you see in debug monitor `po myString` it will be `{  "userpass" : "",  "apikey" : "=",  "deviceid" : "",  "username" : ""}`, this slash just in code not in program

Answer (score -1):

In objective-c

```
NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [yourString 
   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
All special characters with in string must use extra \ (escape sequence) to recognize the actual value    

 [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""];
    or string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

hope you will be clear
```

Comment: [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""];

Comment: r u still facing the same issue?
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""]

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Yes bcz of all spl characters with in string must use extra \ (escape sequence) to recognize the actual  value.